# How to set background color in border in CSS

Tags: css, border

```
.click{
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #e4910c;
    border-radius: 200px;
    transition: background-color 0.1s;
}

a:hover{
background-color: #e4910c;
color: white;
}
```

I tried to set everywhere in border to #e4910c; But the text has padding. So I only can set text's background color to #e4910c, not everywhere in the border. 
[image]
How to do that? Thank you in advance

Comment: Set a default background color?

Comment: Exactly as @Oisin said. You can set a default background color. Try putting it in your button. That should work

Comment: I see your point. But how to put that in my border? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quiet sure about what you want, but let me know if this will suit you:

- using only `a` instead of two tags (which I understand you are using)

#### Snipet

```css
a {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #e4910c;
  border-radius: 200px;
  transition: background-color 0.1s;
  display:inline-block; /* demo purposes - optional */
  color:#e4910c;
  text-decoration:none;
    
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #e4910c;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Text link</a>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want! Could you tell me the difference between these solutions? Why if I just use a tag, background will not only work in text, also work in padding part?